# Twilio Client DTMF not working

Tags: php, javascript, twilio

I am working on a Twilio Client application and I am having a hard time sending DTMF tones. Here is the code I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.each(['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','star','pound'], function(index, value) { 
    $('#button' + value).click(function(){ 
        if(connection) {
            if (value=='star')
                connection.sendDigits('*')
            else if (value=='pound')
                connection.sendDigits('#')
            else
                connection.sendDigits(value)
            return false;
        } 
     });
  });
</script>


<div id="dialpad">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="1" id="button1"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="2" id="button2"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="3" id="button3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="4" id="button4"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="5" id="button5"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="6" id="button6"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="7" id="button7"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="8" id="button8"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="9" id="button9"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="*" id="buttonstar"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="0" id="button0"></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="#" id="buttonpound"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

When I call my test number and press a button on the dialpad it does not send the values. Any help on this is greatly appreciated?

Comment: Hi, Just reading the javascript provided it's not clear you initialize the `connection` variable anywhere. Also, can you confirm with a console.log that the each() function is actually executing when you click on any of the inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script block you need to have the connection object available. So above your function, you'll need something like:

```
var connection = null;
Twilio.Device.setup('your token');
params = { "number" : "5559871234", "outbound" : "true" };
connection = Twilio.Device.connect(params);
```

Essentially, this function just needs to "see" the connection variable. If your javascript files are in different places and you can't consolidate them, you can make the connection object global (not ideal) at least to see if you can get it working.

```
connection = null;
```

(without the "var" first)